# Automatic target a phone call when my html page is refresh

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, tel

I need to create a jquery code to call a number on page loading. The code is added but it not working with the phone.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0" />
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="add_redirect" href="tel:+1-541-754-3010">Call</a>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#add_redirect").trigger("click");
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Always supply the phone number using the international dialing format: the plus sign (**+**), country code, area code, and number. While not absolutely necessary, it’s a good idea to separate each segment of the number with a hyphen (-) for easier reading and better auto-detection.

For example:

> tel:+1-303-499-7111

More info [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/click-to-call/).

The click event doesn't work for hyperlinks.
You can use this **workaround** instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var href = $("#add_redirect").attr('href');
    window.location.href = href;
});
```

Comment: I just tried with your suggestion but it till not working with a mobile phone. Please check my code <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
window.location.href = 'tel:+1-303-499-7111';
});
</script>

Comment: @AnirbanHajra You do have jQuery loaded do you? Please post the entire html file in your original question.

Comment: I just post full of my HTML file code please check and help me.

Comment: The problem is the click event not working. I posted a workaround in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document ).ready(function() {
  $("#add_redirect").trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="add_redirect" href="tel:+012345678">Call</a>
```

Comment: I already tried with your code but it till not working on the mobile phone.